# Do you only need to build the googletest library once?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, static-libraries, googletest

So firstly I'm new to testing frameworks and relatively new to C++ but am trying to wrap my head around GoogleTest. I'm working on a Windows machine, running "Git for Windows" (MSYS) and MinGW whilst using Sublime Text as my code editor. I am using make as my build tool, although the more I learn about cmake and its cross-platform focus makes me wonder if I should switch to let cmake create makefiles for me. (that's probably a whole other question)

What I'm struggling to understand is what precisly to do with the GoogleTest source package. I realise that I need to build the source into the library and then include that when compiling my tests, but how should I go about doing this? Google includes a cmake build script that generates env/compilier specific makefiles for building. Should I be using this? I feel like if i do so and it blindly works a lot of what is happening under the hood will go over my head. The readme file isn't eliviating my issues, as it implies that i should be building the library and my tests each time i wish the run them. Shouldn't a library be a standalone archive that needs compiling only once? I'm confused and I'm sure its my fault but i'd appreciate it if someone shed some light on this process for me.

Comment: If you have a CMake project, just add it as a subproject and build it along with the rest (CMake should make sure it isn't rebuilt if not needed). Otherwise just build it once and use the static libraries as you would with any other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that **make** will not rebuild **gtest** if you don't change anything in gtest source code.

Below is my approach to the usage of cmake and gtest for unit testing.

You can add gtest source code by adding it as subdirectory in the root CMakeLists.txt file.

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/gtest ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/gtest/include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/gtest)
```

My application consist of individual modules containing test folder for unit testing. I have the following boilerplate loop to add each test to the global scope.

```
file(GLOB TEST_SRC_FILES *.cpp) 
foreach(TEST_SRC_PATH ${TEST_SRC_FILES})
 #get filename of your test without extension
 get_filename_component(TEST_NAME ${TEST_SRC_PATH} NAME_WE)

 add_executable(${TEST_NAME} ${TEST_NAME})

 #here you link the test executable with gtest
 target_link_libraries(${TEST_NAME} gtest  gtest_main)

 #-----------------------------
 # you can link here your test to external libraries
 #-----------------------------

 add_test(${TEST_NAME} ${TEST_NAME})

 #this is a list of all tests
 set(PROJECT_TEST_NAMES ${PROJECT_TEST_NAMES} ${TEST_NAME})  
endforeach()

 #This assigns the list of tests to a property. This make the list available from the root scope.
 get_property(UNIT_TESTS GLOBAL PROPERTY UNIT_TESTS)
 set(UNIT_TESTS ${UNIT_TESTS} ${PROJECT_TEST_NAMES})
 set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY UNIT_TESTS ${UNIT_TESTS} )
```

Finally, in the root scope, I add a custom target named *check* which runs ctest on my unit tests.

```
#-----------------------------
# Running unit tests
#-----------------------------
get_property(UNIT_TESTS GLOBAL PROPERTY UNIT_TESTS)
if(DEFINED UNIT_TESTS)
    add_custom_target(check COMMAND ctest -VV
                             DEPENDS ${UNIT_TESTS})
endif()
```

When I run `make check`, it runs unit tests from all modules, whereas `make` compiles without tests.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cmake syntax, but I think I see what's going on here and it seems like a nice solution. Would you recommend using cmake? I was originally using make to build my projects.

Comment: cmake is used to generate projects, make is a tool to actually build your project. They are tools for different purposes, hence can't be compared. Cmake generates makefiles you need to compile your code with make.

Comment: I understand that, but my current solution has been hardcoding a makefile, would you recommend generating one through cmake?

Comment: I'll look into why I should do so ^^ thanks for all the help.